# Pass additional parameter in call function of custom keras layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I created a custom keras layer with the purpose of manually changing activations of previous layer during inference. Following is basic layer that simply multiplies the activations with a number.

```
import numpy as np
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import Layer
import tensorflow as tf

class myLayer(Layer):

    def __init__(self, n=None, **kwargs):
        self.n = n
        super(myLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):

        self.output_dim = input_shape[1]
        super(myLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs):

        changed = tf.multiply(inputs, self.n)

        forTest  = changed
        forTrain = inputs

        return K.in_train_phase(forTrain, forTest)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], self.output_dim)
```

It works fine when I use it like this with IRIS dataset

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units, input_shape=(5,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(myLayer(n=3))
model.add(Dense(units))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(3))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
model.summary()
```

However now I want to move 'n' from **init** to the call function so I can apply different values of n after training to evaluate model. The idea is to have a placeholder inplace of n which can be initialzed with some value before calling the evaluate function on it. I am not sure how to achieve this. What would the correct approach for this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should work the same way the [Concatenate](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/merging/concatenate.py#L29) layer does.

These layers taking multiple inputs rely on the inputs (and the input shapes) being passed in a **list**.

See the verification part in `build`, `call` and `comput_output_shape`:

```
def call(self,inputs):
    if not isinstance(inputs, list):
        raise ValueError('This layer should be called on a list of inputs.')
    
    mainInput = inputs[0]
    nInput = inputs[1]

    changed = tf.multiply(mainInput,nInput)
    #I suggest using an equivalent function in K instead of tf here, if you ever want to test theano or another backend later. 
    #if n is a scalar, then just "changed=nInput * mainInput" is ok

    #....the rest of the code....
```

Then you call this layer passing a list to it. But for that, I strongly recommend you move away from `Sequential` models. They're pure limitation.

```
from keras.models import Model

inputTensor = Input((5,)) # the original input (from your input_shape)

#this is just a suggestion, to have n as a manually created var
#but you can figure out your own ways of calculating n later
nInput = Input((1,))
    #old answer: nInput = Input(tensor=K.variable([n]))

#creating the graph
out = Dense(units, input_shape=(5,),activation='relu')(inputTensor)

#your layer here uses the output of the dense layer and the nInput
out = myLayer()([out,nInput])
    #here you will have to handle n with the same number of samples as x. 
    #You can use `inputs[1][0,0]` inside the layer

out = Dense(units,activation='relu')(out)
out = Dense(3,activation='softmax')(out)

#create the model with two inputs and one output:
model = Model([inputTensor,nInput], out)
    #nInput is now a part of the model's inputs

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
```

Using the old answer, with `Input(tensor=...)`, the model will not demand, as usually would happen, that you pass 2 inputs to the `fit` and `predict` methods.

But using the new option, with `Input(shape=...)` it will demand two inputs, so:

```
nArray = np.full((X_train.shape[0],1),n)
model.fit([X_train,nArray],Y_train,....)
```

Unfortunately, I coulnd't make it work with `n` having only one element. It must have exactly the same number of samples as (this is a keras limitation).

Comment: Thanks Daniel. That is exactly what I was looking for. However I tried your code and it is giving me the following error:
[My Code](https://gist.github.com/ahwaleed/128493253717e67548ef18d75baa6979)
**Error**
[Error](https://gist.github.com/ahwaleed/0ec9a5e1439af402612d74cdd5f30296) Do you know why I am getting this?

Comment: An [issue](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/7362) here says that:

This is a symptom of one of two things:

your inputs don't come from keras.layers.Input()
your outputs aren't the output of a Keras layer.
Make sure that you are only passing to Model 1) inputs generated via Input 2) outputs generated by a Keras layer, with no further ops applied to them.

Comment: Ok, sorry for that. Now it's working. Notice that `nInput` is now an `Input`, and that the model must be created taking it into account in `Model([inputTensor,nInput],out)`

Comment: Yup that worked like a charm! Thanks. I do have two questions:
1) Why does it not demand the second input in the model.fit?
2) I am interested in using model.evaluate with different of 'n' to analyse the effect of n on test error. How would I achieve that?

Comment: It's the first time I see the model not demand it on fit. It's probably because of the `tensor` parameter in the input instead of just a shape. -- In order to pass `n` in the input you can try to make it `nInput = Input(batch_input_shape=(1,1))`, then you pass it to the fit method. (Not sure if Keras will demand that the batch be the same size... (if so, then you can try `nInput=Input((1,))` and pass an array o n's to the `fit` method, the same length as training data.

Comment: Yes it asks for the same batch size. I tried `n = K.placeholder(shape=(1,))` and then `auxInput = Input(tensor=n)` but then with `model.fit([X_train, np.array([3])], Y_train,  epochs=epochs)` I get the error `ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 arrays but instead got the following list of 2 arrays:` **and with** `model.fit(X_train, Y_train,  epochs=epochs)` **I get the error** `InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor`

Comment: How should I initialize the placeholder with model.fit?

Comment: I've tried many things, and the only that actually worked was using `Input((1,))` for `nInput`, and then training passing n as `n=np.full((X_train.shape[0],1), nValue)` --- See updated answer.

Comment: Right! Thanks Daniel.

Comment: Aah! Found an answer, using K.variable instead of K.placeholder: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46234722/initialize-keras-placeholder-as-input-to-a-custom-layer/46239501#46239501

Comment: OMG, I would give you like 10 upvotes if I could, thank you! 2 days stuck with this.