# Initialize keras placeholder as Input to a Custom Layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I want to manipulate the activations of the previous layer with a custom keras layer. The below layer simply multiplies a number with the activations of the previous layer.

```
class myLayer(Layer):

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(myLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def build(self, input_shape):
    self.output_dim = input_shape[0][1]
    super(myLayer, self).build(input_shape)

def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
    if not isinstance(inputs, list):
        raise ValueError('This layer should be called on a list of inputs.')

    mainInput = inputs[0]
    nInput = inputs[1]

    changed = tf.multiply(mainInput,nInput)

    forTest  = changed
    forTrain = inputs[0]

    return K.in_train_phase(forTrain, forTest)

def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    print(input_shape)
    return (input_shape[0][0], self.output_dim)
```

I am creating the model as

```
inputTensor = Input((5,))
out = Dense(units, input_shape=(5,),activation='relu')(inputTensor)

n = K.placeholder(shape=(1,))
auxInput = Input(tensor=n)
out = myLayer()([out, auxInput])

out = Dense(units, activation='relu')(out)
out = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(out)
model = Model(inputs=[inputTensor, auxInput], outputs=out)   
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics='acc'])
```

I get this error when I try to use

`model.fit(X_train, Y_train,  epochs=epochs, verbose=1)`

**Error**

```
InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_3' with dtype float and shape [1]
```

And when I try to give the value to the placeholder like

`model.fit([X_train, np.array([3])], Y_train,  epochs=epochs, verbose=1)`

**I get:**

```
ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 arrays but instead got the following list of 2 arrays:
```

How should I initialize this placeholder? My goal is to use model.evaluate to test effect of different values of n the model during inference.
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a solution avoiding the use of an array for `n`.

Instead of using a `placeholder`, use a `K.variable`:

```
n = K.variable([someInitialValue])
auxInput = Input(tensor=n)
```

Then you can set the value of `n` like this at any time, even after compiling the model:

```
K.set_value(n,[anotherValue])
```

This allows you to keep training without having to recompile the model, and without passing `n` to the `fit` method.

```
model.fit(X_train,Y_train,....)
```

---

If working with many inputs like that, you can make it:

```
n = K.variable([val1,val2,val3,val4]) #tensor definition
K.set_value(n,[new1,new2,new3,new4]) #changing values
```

And inside the layers, the second input which is the tensor for `n` will have 4 elements:

```
n1 = inputs[1][0]
n2 = inputs[1][1]
....
```

Comment: @Daniel Möller Here is a problem, I think the original code is limited to the case when batch size is fixed as 1? How you can generalize this setting for batch size unknown cases?

Comment: There is no limitation about batch size in these codes. The input with `tensor=...` can take any tensor size (it even can disrespect the Keras rule that the first dimension should be a batch size). If you have the same number of samples in the "tensor" as you have in the main input, then just use a regular input.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Input(shape=(1,))` instead of a placeholder. Also, there's no need to provide `input_shape` to `Dense` since `Input(shape=(5,))` already handles it.

```
inputTensor = Input(shape=(5,))
out = Dense(units, activation='relu')(inputTensor)

auxInput = Input(shape=(1,))
out = myLayer()([out, auxInput])
```

Repeat the value `n` when feeding it into the model, for example:

```
n = 3
n_array = np.array([n] * len(X_train))
model.fit([X_train, n_array], Y_train,  epochs=1, verbose=1)
```

### Edit:

What's been described above is just a quick hack. If you want to provide multiple parameters to the layer, you can initialize `K.variable` in the constructor `__init__()`.

For example,

```
class myLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, default_scale=3.0, default_shift=1.0, **kwargs):
        self.scale = K.variable(default_scale)
        self.shift = K.variable(default_shift)
        super(myLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        return K.in_train_phase(inputs, self.scale * inputs + self.shift)

inputTensor = Input(shape=(5,))
out = Dense(units, activation='relu')(inputTensor)
out = myLayer(name='my_layer')(out)
out = Dense(units, activation='relu')(out)
out = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(out)
model = Model(inputs=inputTensor, outputs=out)
```

By assigning a name to this layer, it'll be easier to get the variables and modify the value in test phase. E.g. , `K.set_value(model.get_layer('my_layer').scale, 5)`.

Comment: Yup that worked. But eventually I would need to pass more parameters than just a single n. Then I want to have more functionality done in the call method of myLayer. Do you think there would be a more efficient way then multiplying the list of arguments by len(X_train)?

Comment: Nice. I will try using this approach.