# Keras + DataFrameMapper + make_pipeline, input_dim dilemma

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, keras

I have data that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn_pandas import DataFrameMapper, CategoricalImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, LabelBinarizer
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'y': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    'a': [2, 1, 2, 7, 8, 8, 9],
    'b': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', None, 'b', 'c']
})

y = df['y']
X = df.drop('y', axis=1)
```

I want to use `DataFrameMapper` to pre-process and `KerasClassifier` to predict. All within a convenient `make_pipeline`...

The `DataFrameMapper` part is simple:

```
mapper = DataFrameMapper([
    (['a'], StandardScaler()),
    ('b', [CategoricalImputer(), LabelBinarizer()]),
])
```

And defining the net is easy enough:

```
def model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu', input_dim= **4** ))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

kc = KerasClassifier(build_fn=model, epochs=5, verbose=2)
```

Putting it all in a `make_pipeline` is simple too:

```
pipe = make_pipeline(mapper, kc)
pipe.fit(X, y)

pipe.predict_proba(
    pd.DataFrame({
        'y': [0],
        'a': [2],
        'b': ['b']
    })
)
```

But here's the rub... I hardcoded the `input_dim` for the Classifier... and I can't in production, because I don't necessarily know what dimensions the `DataFrameMapper` will spit out... might be 4 might be 5 might be 11... So my real question: **How can I pass the shape/output_dim of `DataFrameMapper` to the input_dim of `KerasClassifier` in the `make_pipeline` flow**?

Thanks!

Comment: this answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/46237943/4132383