# How to specify the input_shape(input_dim) in the Keras Sequential model dynamically while using pipeline?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, neural-network, deep-learning

I create a Keras Sequential model by passing a list of layer instances to the constructor. For that, I need to pass an input_shape argument to the first layer to create_model() function. Generally, I can get a shape tuple like this:

```py
input_shape=(len(X_train.keys()),)
```

Meanwhile, I am using the pipeline to take care of my preprocessing steps such as Imputing, Scaling, Encoding, Feature Selection, and etc. As a result, the number of variables/features after preprocessing is not the same as before, and I am not able to get the number of nodes that I want to add in this first hidden layer. Then, I got an error regarding the dense_1_input, and after that, I can update the shape accordingly.

Now, I want to know is there a way to specify the input_shape dynamically when using the pipeline.

#### Use pipelines to clean up modeling code

```py
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel, RFE
from sklearn.linear_model import LassoCV

numerical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')),
    ('feature_selection', SelectFromModel(LassoCV(cv=5))),
    ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
])

categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')),
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),
    ('feature_selection', SelectFromModel(LassoCV(cv=5))),
])

# Bundle preprocessing for numerical and categorical data
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', numerical_transformer, numerical_cols),
        ('cat', categorical_transformer, categorical_cols)
    ])
```

#### Initializing the ANN Model

```py
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from keras.callbacks import Callback, EarlyStopping


def create_model(optimizer='adagrad',
                 kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',
                 dropout=0.2):

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer,
                    input_shape=(len(X_train.keys()),)))  # len(X_train.keys()) is not correct here
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1))

    model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer=optimizer,
                  metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])

    return model
```

My desired output is to access the shape of dataframe after preprocessing with pipeline.

This is probably a similar unanswered question:
[Keras + DataFrameMapper + make_pipeline, input_dim dilemma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48216358/keras-dataframemapper-make-pipeline-input-dim-dilemma)