# Reshape neural network layer output to become like a timeseries

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Say the output of a neural network layer with shape (None,1) looks like

`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7........]`,

how can I reshape this in a custom layer to have an output to have an output shape like

```
[[1,2,3],
 [2,3,4],
 [3,4,5],
 [4,5,6],
 [5,6,7],
...
]
```

so that I can use this new reshaped output in the next layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method [`tf.signal.frame`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/signal/frame) that can do what you want.

```py
import tensorflow as tf


x = tf.range(100)
ts = tf.signal.frame(x, 3, 1)

print(ts)
# tf.Tensor(
# [[ 0  1  2]
#  [ 1  2  3]
#  [ 2  3  4]
# ...
```

Or if you need it to be a layer

```py
class FrameLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def call(self, x, window=3):
        return tf.signal.frame(x, window, 1, axis=1)


x = tf.reshape(tf.range([5 * 100]), (-1, 100))
out = FrameLayer()(x)

print(out.shape)
# (5, 98, 3)

print(out)
# tf.Tensor(
# [[[  0   1   2]
#   [  1   2   3]
#   [  2   3   4]
#   ...
#   [ 95  96  97]
#   [ 96  97  98]
#   [ 97  98  99]]
#   ...
#  [[100 101 102]
#   [101 102 103]
#   [102 103 104]
#   ...
#   [195 196 197]
#   [196 197 198]
#   [197 198 199]]
#   ...
```

Comment: Thanks @gobrewers14.  Can the window size be programmable in a Keras customer layer?

Comment: Yes, see the 3rd arg in the `call` method above.

Comment: True, but we don't have access to the method 'call' when compiling and fitting with the model.  Probably can do it with __init__, but Keras is picky with things that set the shape.

Comment: I never use keras for that reason. It's is nice when you are trying to classify mnist, but it's a disaster when you start trying to write customizations. IMO, `Sequential` is much more inhibiting than convenient. There are solutions though, for what you are trying to do with keras. See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46195201/pass-additional-parameter-in-call-function-of-custom-keras-layer)

Answer (score 2):

Slice and concatenate:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class toRNN(keras.layers.Layer):
  def call(self, inputs):
    output = tf.concat(
      (
        inputs[:-2], 
        inputs[1:-1], 
        inputs[2:]
      ), 
      -1)
    return output

output = tf.expand_dims(tf.range(100), -1)
output = toRNN()(output)
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrey, I should have specified that this must be part of a Keras custom layer so that I can use this reshaped output for the next layer.  It seems your answer still works, any reason why you think it would or wouldn't as a custom layer?